# Getting a webhook on a PHP file, need to pass variables to JS file (write to firebase)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I am using a PHP file to retrieve a webhook. Everytime data is passed, the php file will parse and create a variable with some string.

I have another .js file that writes to firebase (using server side using firebase-admin).

How do i pass the variable to the .js file so that I can write the variable data to fb?

PHP:

```
<?php
  echo "<script>var invoiceId = '<?= $invoiceId ?>';</script>";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='../firebase_webhook.js'></script>";
?>
```

firebase_webhook.js:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = {//credentials};
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://...firebaseio.com"
});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog");

var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set({
  test_data: {
    full_name: invoiceId
  }
});
```

Comment: You're not invoking the javascript as a node process, but are trying to include it as a script. That's not going to work. You might want to look at how to run a node.js program from php: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+how+to+run+a+node.js+program+from+php&oq=how+to+run+a+node.js+program+from+php&aqs=chrome..69i64j69i57.1120j0j7&{google:bookmarkBarPinned}sourceid=chrome&{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}ie=UTF-8